# Recette de bonne « fame » ou « femme » ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

J'ai longtemps utilisé l'expression de *recette de bonne femme* comme équivalent de *recette de grand mère*.

J'ai lu récemment une autre orthographe : *recette de bonne fame*. Ce qui peut paraître logique, fame, « famous » en anglais pour « célèbre », une recette fameuse en français, c'est cohérent.

Mon grand ami le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rem%C3%A8de_de_bonne_femme) a l'air plutôt rangé du côté de la première orthographe, mais j'ai eu beau parcourir ses sources, **impossible de trouver une info fiable qui aille dans un sens ou dans l'autre**.

Comment: L'explication  : http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/un-remede-de-bonne-femme.php  mais il est sûr que de nos jours, on n'emploie plus que « l'expression de bonne femme »

Comment: Ah c'est curieux, j'aurais justement pensé que le "remède de bonne _fame_" aurait eu une histoire plus ancienne. Intéressant ton lien, dommage que les sources soient générales au site, et non pas par article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On trouve « famé(e) » dans n'importe quel dictionnaire : « Qui jouit d'une certaine réputation. »

Mais on trouve aussi l'entrée « fame » dans le Dictionnaire du Moyen Français;

- Rumeur, bruit qui court
- Réputation, renommée

Answer (score 6):

Cela vient de l'italien *buona fama* : bonne renommée.

> *Recette de bonne femme* : recettes (médicinales) de bonne réputation.

*[Paracelse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracelse)* a construit une partie de sa pharmacopée sur les recettes récoltées chez les femmes (de toute extraction) ayant la renommée de guérir ou de soulager.

Par la suite la revanche des mandarins a disqualifié l'origine de ces onguents et autres remèdes pour s'approprier la gloire et faire bonne fortune,
... d'où la descente de *buona fama* en *bonnes femmes* (la bonté liée aux femmes) expression qui par l'usage est devenu péjorative.

Comment: Tiens c'est original que tu cites ici Paracelse, c'est le personnage historique qui a inspiré le personnage Bombastus d'une de mes bande dessinées préférées ! Le lien entre `buona fama` et `bonne fame` semble tout à fait logique pour deux langues latines.

Comment: Très fascinant. Par hazard de l'homophone, la phrase ne se traduit pas pratiquement en Français. Fame est un mot très rare en français, a cause de la confusion de femme qui brouillerait les conversations.

Answer (score 3):

La fame en ancien français c'est la renommée, la réputation. Dans les lettres de grâce données à un criminel par l'autorité souveraine on trouve souvent une formule comme "remis en ses bons fame honneur et renommée". Dans le dictionnaire de Godefroy (français médiéval) on trouve quantité d'exemples avec des orthographes variées puisque rien n'est encore fixé: "bonne famme", "faume", "falme", etc. Cependant la forme "remède bonne fame" donc de bonne réputation est une déformation de la vraie formule "remède de bonne femme". L'Académie l'explique : "L’expression «remèdes de bonne femme» a subi ce que les linguistes appellent la remotivation étymologique (...) Quelque habile latiniste s’est un jour avisé qu’en latin fama signifiait «renommée»..." ce qui permettait de rehausser la signification de "femme". Et: "Et s’il en était encore besoin, un petit détour par des langues voisines confirmerait ce qu’écrivait Pierre Larousse : nos amis anglais parlent de old wives’ remedy, littéralement «remède de vieilles épouses», nos amis allemands disent Hausmittel, familièrement, «le truc de la maison». Cette notion de remède familial, «fait à la maison», se retrouve dans l’espagnol remedio casero (...) nos amis italiens (...) parlent de rimedio empirico." http://www.academie-francaise.fr/des-remedes-de-bonne-femme-ou-de-bonne-fame