# Usage of 'hot' meaning 'good-looking' or 'attractive'

Tags: traduction, culture

The word 'hot' in English is usually perceived as:

> an adjective that conveys the degree of heat possessed by an object.

A French translation for 'hot' in this context would be 'chaud'.

However, it has become increasingly common to call a person 'hot' which conveys the meaning that that person is extremely physically attractive. This probably stems from the meaning that 'hot' also refers to:

> filled with passionate excitement, anger, or other strong emotion.

Hence anything that can induce such a feeling is also termed as 'hot'.

My question is: Is there any French equivalent of such a notion. 
For example, how would I say "Damn, she looks so hot, I want to take her home with me tonight".

Of course in English, various other phrases have also sprung up such as 'sizzling' and 'smoking' hot. I wonder how French speakers convey such notions.

Comment: A word of warning: “*elle est chaude*” is a false friend, it would usually be interpreted as “she's horny”.

Comment: Worth pointing the difference between "Elle est chaude" and "Elle a chaud".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"**Bandante**", "**Baisable**" are disrepectfull for women. You can't (and shoudln't) say it to her face without taking a slap. It's related to fuck (baisable = fuckable).

The slang the most use by my generation (18-30 yo) is "**Bonne**". It still keep a bit of disrespect but you can use it among friends without being the redneck of the group. "Bonne" comes from *"bonne à baiser"* (good to fuck) but it has lost more and more its sexual connotation.

If you want to say to a girl she's hot, you can say **sexy**.

To summarize:

- **Bonne** : among friends or with a girl you know well.
- **Sexy**:  without any disrepect

Comment: If you're British, 'bonne' is good equivalent to 'fit', so it does sound a bit chavvy and Vicky Pollard-y if spoken out loud in public but ok among friends.

Comment: careful though: 'bonne femme' as a frozen expression means matron-ish woman or cackling woman, 'femme bonne' means 'fit woman'. Also: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8085/recette-de-bonne-fame-ou-femme

Comment: Note that, in a typically sexist way, "bonne" only apply to female people; no one says that "un mec est bon" (it won't be understood at all). "sexy" would work for both genders, "baisable" could also work. For "bandante", you could conceivably say "bandant" to apply to a male person but it carries an obvious assumption that the speaker is male.

Answer (score 19):

The best equivalent I find is "canon" because it is not especially sexual and is of the same 'language politeness level'.

I mean that it's not particularly slang but you wouldn't hear it in any formal context.

It is an adjective :

> Scarlett Johansson est canon.

Or a noun, by the way Smoking hot could be :

> Keira Knightley est un super canon.

I guess it comes from the expression "canons de beauté" which mean the reference criteria (to decide what is beautiful) commonly and currently accepted.

My explanation aren't very clear but the equivalent of "hot" is definitely "canon".

Comment: I wouldn't say that "canon" is an *equivalent* of "hot" -- it's very much dated.

Answer (score 12):

It's probably as dated as I am, but B. Bardot was "**une bombe**."

Comment: Here are a couple of non-heat-related compliments suitable for flirting: “[plutôt] pas mal” and “[très] bien faite.”  “T’es [plutôt] pas mal, toi [aussi].*”... ”T’es [très] bien faite, toi [aussi].*”   **(add « aussi » if you’re returning a similar compliment) (and it would be "bien fait" if your are flirting with a guy)

Comment: Meilleur équivalent, bien que ce ne soit pas un adjectif. *Canon* est ringard, *Bonne* reste péjoratif.

Answer (score 3):

*Canon* comes to mind, although probably more used by 30+ y/o generations than younger people.

> Cette fille / ce mec est carrément canon

In "today's" language, *hot* would be somewhere between *charmant/e/* (cute-ish, not rude but may convey sexual / flirty allusion) and *bonne* (used for women only, more disrespectful, sexist). I can't think of a strict equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I am here assuming that the goal is to properly address a woman.
If not, then all the slang words previously proposed are fine (if used among friends only), **bonne** being the more common.
Otherwise, I concur that **canon** might be the closest translation although it is clearly outdated.
Using the word **sexy** is probably a bit more modern.
But in truth we Frenchmen do not have (to my knowledge) this particular concept available on our language.
Hope I've been useful.

Answer (score -1):

The nearest I can think of is  *bandant(e)*:

> *Elle est si bandante que je la mettrais bien dans mon lit ce soir*.

No direct relationship to heat in *bandante*, but a direct reference to the male organ in erection.

*Baisable* is another possibility (from *baiser* ("fuck") ). But the word does not convey such a strong urge as *bandante*.

Note that both words are very informal, probably more than "hot" because of their direct sexual significance.

Comment: Is there any such overused French expression that the French use while flirting?

Comment: bandant(e) is adult language

Comment: I've only ever seen teenagers & movie characters use "bandante", though. (Not so adult after all :P)