# Does the term "canon" apply just as well to men?

Tags: usage

> Qui c'est, la **meuf** la plus **canon** au monde ?

I was under the impression that the adjective "canon" is reserved for referring to women, but can the term actually be used just as well to refer to men?

> Le **mec** le plus **canon** que j'aie jamais rencontré.

Comment: *Meuf* ?? Hmmm... J'avoue ne pas pratiquer ce français-là. Mais, pour avoir tout de même rencontré quelques canons **de beauté** c'est bien à dire un étant animé ou inanimé répondant à tous les critères d'une esthétique formelle, je dirais que oui, évidemment, *canon* s'applique nécessairement à n'importe quel étant : inanimé ou animé, humain ou animal, mâle ou femelle. ! Forcement !

Comment: Par ailleurs... dans cette forme de langage... il n'y a que moi ou vous aussi trouvez que le subjonctif il fait un peu... comment dire... intrus ?

Answer (score 2):

The colloquial noun *canon* is masculine but generally refer to a woman.

> *Y'a un canon qui vient d'arriver !*

When used as an adjective, *canon* (which is close to "hot") keeps the masculine form, might not mark the plural and can be used for both genders :

> *Elle est canon.*
>
> *Il est canon.*
>
> *Ils sont canon(s).*

Despite matching another meaning of *canon* like in *un canon de beauté* (formal), I doubt they share the same origin. I suspect the power and potential "damages" this *canon* (cannon) can cause is a more plausible explanation. Another powerful device is a bomb which belongs to the same military vocabulary :

> *Cette fille, c'est une bombe !*.

See also [Usage of 'hot' meaning 'good-looking' or 'attractive'](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/usage-of-hot-meaning-good-looking-or-attractive)

Notes:

If you use *meuf*, chances are high you say *c'est qui* instead of *qui c'est*:

> C'est qui, la meuf la plus canon du monde ?

and you might also use *keum* (although less common than *meuf*) instead of *mec* :

> Le keum le plus canon que j'aie rencontré !

However, *canon* is being replaced by *hot* among the younger generation and *verlan* popularity is fading out so that might be:

> *Le mec le plus hot que j'aie rencontré !*

Comment: Il y avait aussi le bikini, venté comme bombe anatomique...

Answer (score 1):

Not only can it apply to men, but also to some objects or concepts !

Ex:

> C'est vraiment un film canon !
>
> Ce coureur a pris un départ canon.

Comment: Yes, and these examples, especially the second and, seem in line with a military origin of *canon* (blast effect) instead of *canonique / canon de beauté*.